# Android SQLite show specific row on spinner selected

Tags: java, android, sqlite, listview, android-arrayadapter

I got a record high score from 3 difficulty which is: Easy, Medium, Hard. All data goes into 1 table. And I got 1 activity to show all the high scores.

In that activity, I created a spinner to let users select which data of difficulty they want to show. All data will be shown in the listview(ScoreView).

Here I want to do is show the specific data when the user is selected on the spinner.

Is there any way to do it?

This is my database:

```
 public Data_Collect[] getScore() {
    Data_Collect[] data = null;
    String[] colums = {"Difficult", "BRedo", "BCorrect"};
    String orderBy = "Difficult ASC";
    Cursor cursor = getReadableDatabase().query(
            "score",
            colums,
            null, null, null, null,
            orderBy);
    if (cursor.getCount()>0 && cursor.moveToNext()) {

        data = new Data_Collect[cursor.getCount()];
        int counter = 0;

        do {

            data[counter] = new Data_Collect(
                    cursor.getString(0),
                    cursor.getInt(1),
                    cursor.getInt(2));
            counter++;

        }
        while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    cursor.close();
    return data;
}
```

This is my activity:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapterDifficult = new ArrayAdapter<>(
            Score.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Difficulty
    );
    SpinnerDifficulty.setAdapter(adapterDifficult);
    SpinnerDifficulty.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            RecordDB db = new RecordDB(Score.this);
            Data_Collect[] data = db.getScore();
            db.close();

            if (data != null) {
                adapter = new RecordAdapter(Score.this, R.layout.recordlist, R.id.text_Difficulty, data);
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        ScoreView.setAdapter(adapter);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }).start();

}


@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

}
```

Comment: Hi Calvin.
I think you’d better pass your level of difficulty to getScore() method at onItemSelect — e.g. getScodre(Difficult) — and get specific data for this level and then notify the adapter to show desirable data.

Comment: HI, do you mean that put the Runnable inside the onItemSelect? but how to show the specific row?

Comment: You should change the query and get specific column because as I realized you store your desirable data in specific columns:  
     Cursor cursor = getReadableDatabase().query(
            "score",
            colums,
            null, null, null, null,
          orderBy); 

to ——>

  Cursor cursor = getReadableDatabase().query(
            "score",
            "Difficult",
            null, null, null, null,
          orderBy);

Comment: OIC, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Define where Difficult = 'Easy'

```
Data_Collect[] data = null;
String[] colums = {"Difficult", "BRedo", "BCorrect"};
String orderBy = "Difficult ASC";
Cursor cursor = getReadableDatabase().query(
        "score",
        colums,
        "Difficult ='Easy'", null, null, null,
        orderBy);
```